# Changing route using an HTML form action in Chrome (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-routing

I have an angularJS application which shares data between 3 controllers using a service. I route between the views using a button within an html form. The action attribute of the form is set to the URL of the destination route.

In Firefox there doesn’t seem to be a problem, however Chrome inserts a question mark into the URL and this appears to restart the application and drop the shared service:

Firefox result:

**"http:// localhost/myApp/app/#/thirdScreen"** (no problem)

Chrome result:

**"http:// localhost/myApp/app/?#/thirdScreen"** (drops the service, application seems to restart and shared service data is lost).

However routing back and forth several times in a row seems to solve the issue for the remainder of the application lifetime in Chrome.

- What does the question mark mean?
- Do I have to use the $location service in my controller to change routes instead or is there another alternative?

Thank you!

**Html**

```
//Extract from the bottom of the secondScreen.html partial

<div class="col-md-12 column">
            <form action="#/thirdScreen">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger">
                              Go to third page 
                 </button>
             </form>
</div>
```

**App.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers',
  'myApp.filters',
  'ngRoute'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
        when("/firstScreen", {templateUrl: "partials/firstScreen.html", controller: 'firstScreenController'}).
        when("/secondScreen", {templateUrl: "partials/secondScreen.html", controller:"secondScreenController"}).
    when("/thirdScreen", {templateUrl: "partials/thirdScreen.html", controller:"thirdScreenController"}).
otherwise({redirectTo: '/firstScreen'});
}]);
```

**Controllers.js**

```
controller('secondScreenController', function($scope, $http, sessionDetailsService, modalService, goodsCheckedInFetchingService) {

    $scope.session = sessionDetailsService;

}).

controller('thirdScreenController', function($scope, $http, sessionDetailsService, modalService, goodsCheckedInFetchingService) {

    $scope.session = sessionDetailsService;

}).
```

Comment: using a form for navigation in angular makes no sense

Comment: Please clarify, is it because you should only use a form for submitting data to the server and loading a new page? The reason I didn't use href was because it was not allowed inside a button element, perhaps I am mistaken?

Comment: why not use an `<a>` tag ?

Comment: Yes probably the best solution, thanks. I was just a little bemused as to why my method worked in Firefox and not Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have set `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('?')` in your code like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('?');
}]);
```

remove this  `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('?');` from your code.

or you have not set this then put this code in app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    }]);
```

Comment: Sorry no effect, I think the problem was that the form element was refreshing the page in Chrome. Replacing the form element with <a> tags fixed the problem. Thanks!